# Cant SSH from Windows PC on LAN but username and password are correct

Tags: windows, authentication, ssh

This is from Windows 10 to Windows 11 OpenSSH installed in Windows Features
I think is has something to do with that last line:

```
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
```

I changed the password and the keys and nothing works.

Comment: How are you calling ssh command

Comment: SSH username@IP address